# How collapse all XAML code sections at once?

Tags: wpf, codeblocks, hotkeys

After short reach i found answers that `CTRL+M, CTRL+L` do that but this only works on specific block and not all the code sections like `Ctrl + m + O` under code behind.

Answer (score 21):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

[See here for the complete list.](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/)

Comment: NOTE: The name of command is "Collapse All Outlining". A related command is "Toggle All Outlining"; when adding to a toolbar via Tools/Customize, that one is found as:  "Edit" / "Outline Toggle All".

Answer (score 3):

Now, in `Visual studio 2019` after selecting the  codes (`Ctrl + A`) the `Ctrl + M + S` works for me to collapse all codes in `XAML`.