# Collapse/Fold all tags for Xaml

Tags: xaml, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut (available with Resharper) to fold all `XAML` tags like this shortcut that works with `C#`?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>
or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

I currently know only one that folds the current tag, but that's useless:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L

Comment: @M.Tovbin This is kind of what I want, but for some reason it expands first and folds later. O.o

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752355/how-collapse-all-xaml-code-sections-at-once

Comment: Not working.. @OscarFonseca